# Need to developed tooltip and hotspots on image using html css and deploy on wordpress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tooltip

I want to create 2 tooltips on hover at icon on image and also when hover on icon it chnage the icon too.
you can also said that it is hotspots on images to display name and thier description.

I have an image and create on hotspots and also diplay information regarding to the part
for you refference I attach image with this problem query.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuAtM.png)

I want to create 2 tooltips on one hover. and add this feature in wordpress website.

Comment: Create an element with the image sizes and place the icons relative to the image - ie % offsets. Try some code and if still stuck post your code here with a description of what isn't working.